# crawl and extract data from a table with xpath

Tags: html, xpath, web-crawler

Im crawling over cities Wiki pages and need to extract the country which the city belong to. I tried to find the `<th>` thats contains the word "country" and than go back to `<tr>` and than find it in `<td>` but the problem there are several cases.

(my code for the first case that works)

```
a = doc.xpath("//table[contains(@class, 'infobox')]")
b = a[0].xpath("//table//th[contains(text(),'Country') or contains(text(),'country')]")
country = b[0].xpath("./../td//a//text()")[0].replace(" ", "_")
```

I know why it doesnt work for the other cases but I dont know how to fix it.

1. the key word "country" is in `<th>`

```html
<tr class="mergedtoprow">
      <th scope="row">Country</th>
      <td>
        <a href="/wiki/Poland" title="Poland">Poland</a>
      </td>
</tr>
```

2. the key word "country" is in `<a>` that in `<span>` that in `<th>`

   `
     
      
       [Constituent country](/wiki/Countries_of_the_United_Kingdom)
       
      
     
     
       
      
      [England](/wiki/England)

   ```html
       <tr class="mergedrow">
         <th scope="row">
          <span class="nowrap">
           <a href="/wiki/Countries_of_the_United_Kingdom" title="Countries of the 
            United Kingdom">Constituent country
           </a>
          </span>
         </th>
         <td>
          <span class="flagicon"><img alt="" src="SRC (never mind)" width="23" 
          height="14" class="thumbborder" srcset="SRC (never mind)" />&#160;
          </span>
          <a href="/wiki/England" title="England">England</a>
         </td>
       </tr>
   ```
3. the key word "country" is in `<a>` that in `<th>`

   ```html
    

          <tr class="mergedrow">
             <th scope="row">
               <a href="/wiki/Countries_of_the_United_Kingdom" title="Countries of the United  Kingdom">Country
               </a>
             </th>
             <td>England</td>
           </tr>
   ```

   `

Comment: "Wiki pages"? If you mean Wikipedia, why don't you use Wikidata?

Comment: It is an university assigment

Comment: sure, I tought it was a bad question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below `XPath` to match required `th` element in all mentioned cases:

```
//th[matches(normalize-space(), "country", "i")]
```

Note that `"i"` flag allows to make case-insensitive search, so both "Country" and "country" should be matched

If your tool only supports `XPath 1.0` you can use

```
//th[contains(.,'Country') or contains(.,'country')]
```